# Determining the voltage of 5 phase PMSM motor

Tags: voltage, ideal, pmsm

As a part of the project, I have to design a 5-Phase PMSM motor, for which want to know the following:

1. How to determine the voltage ?
2. What should be the ideal voltage to use this motor in an electric car? Provided the car has 12 battery packs of 12 volts ( i.e 144 V supply from the battery?)

If, additionally could anyone  suggest me some literatue, it would be a great help.

Comment: Voltage is relatively unimportant. You can (within limits e.g. available wire gauges) rewind the same motor for higher (or lower) voltage, using more (or fewer) turns of thinner (or thicker) wire - just as if it was a transformer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Determine the voltage based on what? On the geometric parameters?
2. You would have to define what do you want to optimize: power? efficiency? cost? space? To keep things simple I would pick an standard voltage level. In your case I would pick 110 V (You still need a DC/DC regulator between battery and machine)

The best book about electric machine design that I know if is in german: "Berechnung elektrischer Maschinen" (https://www.wiley-vch.de/de/fachgebiete/naturwissenschaften/physik-11ph/elektrizitaetslehre-11pha/berechnung-elektrischer-maschinen-978-3-527-40525-1). In english I like "Design of Rotating Electrical Machines" (https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Design+of+Rotating+Electrical+Machines%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118581575)